# Conditional Probability Question (Insurance drivers)

Tags: probability

An insurance company insures E drivers under age 24 and D drivers over 24 years old. Of these drivers, e under 24 and d over 24 had an accident in a 1 year period. A driver insured by this company is chosen at random. Let A be the event that this driver is under 24 and B be the event that this driver did not have an accident in a 1 year period. Find the necessary and su cient condition on e,d,E, and D so that A and B are independent events.

Does anyone know how to approach this? I Have P(AnB)= P(A)P(B) But not sure how to derive expressions in terms of e, E, d and D.

Answer (score 1):

Draw up a two-way table and fill in the data we have been given:

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{cm}|}
\hline  &  \text{under 24}  &\text{over 24} &\text{Total}   \\ \hline \hline \hline\text{accident in last year}& e & d & \\ \hline \text{no accident in last year}&  & & \\ \hline \text{Total}  & E & D & \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Complete the table:

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{cm}|}
\hline  &  \text{under 24}  &\text{over 24} &\text{Total}   \\ \hline \hline \hline\text{accident in last year}& e & d & e+d\\ \hline \text{no accident in last year}&E-e  & D-d&E+D-e-d \\ \hline \text{Total}  & E & D & E+D\\ \hline  \end{array}$$

$A$ is the event that a randomly selected driver is under 24.

$P(A)=\frac{E}{E+D}$

$B$ is the event that a randomly selected driver did not have an accident in a 1 year period.

$P(B)=\frac{E+D-e-d}{E+D}$

$A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$

$A \cap B$ is the event that a randomly selected driver is under 24 and did not have an accident in the last year.

$P(A \cap B)=\frac{E-e}{E+D}$

So requirement is:

$$\frac{E-e}{E+D} = \frac{E}{E+D} \frac{E+D-e-d}{E+D}$$

$$(E+D)(E-e) = E(E+D-e-d)$$

$$E^2+DE-eE-eD = E^2+ED-eE-dE$$

$$eD = dE$$

Comment: Okay thanks, do you know by chance what "sufficiency/necessity" is? I assume its just E, D is non zero, and sufficient condition is the solution you have posted above. 

Thanks again